# Unable to run Unit Tests that uses Microsoft Fakes - Exception in ShimsContext.Create() Method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-fakes

My problem is very similar to one reported here: [UnitTestIsolationException when debugging tests using Fakes](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785030/unittestisolationexception-when-debugging-tests-using-fakes)

However, I am not even able to run the tests. Using the sample code provided here: [Isolating Code Under Test with Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (Getting Started with Shims), I get following exception on running the test below :

the offending line is :

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
```

Exception on running the test:

> Test Name:  TestMethod1
>       Test FullName: TestingShimsAndStubs.UnitTest1.TestMethod1
>       Test Source:  c:\poc\TestingShimsAndStubs\TestingShimsAndStubs\UnitTest1.cs : line 12
>       Test Outcome: Failed
>       Test Duration:  0:00:00.0182403

Result Message:

> Test method TestingShimsAndStubs.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception: 
>           Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException:
>   Failed to get profiler module handle 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\12.0.0\Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Profiler.12.0.0.dll'.
>   The specified module could not be found --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified module could not
>   be found Result StackTrace:
>      at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.LibraryMethods.GetModuleHandle(String
>   fileName)
>          at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.LoadProfilerModule(String
>   profilerPath)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.LoadProfilerModule(String
>   profilerPath)
>          at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
>          at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
>          at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
>          at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
>          at TestingShimsAndStubs.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\poc\TestingShimsAndStubs\TestingShimsAndStubs\UnitTest1.cs:line 16

*I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Edition (Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5) with .Net Framework v 4.6.01055 on my machine. Also tried running the tests on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition as well*

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what VS2013/VS2015 was happening but opening it as an Administrator (Start -> Right Click Visual Studio 2013 -> Run As Administrator ) and then opening the Test project seems to have fixed the issue!!!

Maybe there is some Corporate Policy that is preventing my regular user account to not access the folder. Impersonating an admin account seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for fixing it!

The solution came after opening a post here [Unable to run Unit Tests that uses Microsoft Fakes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fbc0b63c-d316-4096-ba5c-1b076791f38d/unable-to-run-unit-tests-that-uses-microsoft-fakes-exception-in-shimscontextcreate-method?forum=vsunittest)  where one of the admins fixed the issue